# Django grouping dictionary in a template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have this view which is a group list for every session :

```
def group_list():
    attendance = Student.objects.values('session', 'group', 'full_name',).order_by('session','group')
return attendance
```

The dictionary look like so :

```
{'full_name': u'User1', 'session': 1, 'group': u'A'}
{'full_name': u'User2', 'session': 1, 'group': u"B"}
{'full_name': u'User3', 'session': 2, 'group': u"B"}
{'full_name': u'User4', 'session': 99, 'group': u'A'}
{'full_name': u'User5', 'session': 99, 'group': u"C"}
```

Is there a way to make a loop or a nested loop for my template to output something like this ?

```
Session 1 :
    Group A
          -User1
          -...
    Group B
          -User2
Session 2 :
    Group A
    Group B
          -User3
```

Perhaps I did my view wrong and I should generate a slightly different dictionary already grouped by session and groups ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`regroup`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) tag.

For example, assuming you pass `attendance` to template:

```
{% regroup attendance by session as session_list %}
{% for session in session_list %}
Session: {{ session.grouper }}
    {% regroup session.list by group as group_list %}
    {% for group in group_list %}
    Group: {{ group.grouper }}
        {% for student in group.list %}
        - {{ student.full_name }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the django documentation link, that part is very resourceful !